# Type hinting hydrated objects in PHPDoc standard

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm fetching entities with Doctrine and using it to hydrate the results as arrays. The problem is, I'm not sure how to create annotations for this kind of return:

```
@return annotation of method \App\Repository\UserRepository::findOneByIdAsArray() does not specify type hint for items of its traversable return value.
```

How I'm suppose to annotate a return array with a lot of types?

I could use something like this:

```
/**
 * @return (string|int|bool)[]
 */
```

But if the source entity object changes (`UserEntity`), this annotation will not be correct.

I could also do something like this:

```
/**
 * @return UserEntity[]
 */
```

But I don't think its correct because I'm not returning the objects themselves, but the array version of their values.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Separate multiple types by | and using [] in the end to specify it's an array.

Something like:

```
/**
 * @return string|int|bool|UserEntity[]
 */
```

Preferably you use the full namepsace for UserEntity.

```
/**
 * @return string|int|bool|\My\Namespace\UserEntity[]
 */
```

Comment: I'm using `@return mixed[]` for now since the types could be outdated and I can't type hint the object itself it's because it's not actually it.